# Mappings field empty in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to create elasticsearch index using Java API  ,
if we see below index mappings filed is coming as empty .

```
# curl -XGET localhost:9200/initest2
{"initest2":{"aliases":{},**"mappings":{}**,"settings":{"index":{"keyspace":"keyspace_test","number_of_shards":"5","provided_name":"initest2","max_result_window":"10000000","creation_date":"1671025346350","analysis":{"normalizer":{"testnormalizer":{"filter":["asciifolding"],"type":"custom","char_filter":[]}}},"number_of_replicas":"0","uuid":"BK9oTTKETZeWqiuR_tGd8w","version":{"created":"6080499"}}}}}
```

JAVA code :

```
String indexQuery = "";
        StringBuilder indexString = new StringBuilder("");
        String test = "{\"settings\": {\"max_result_window\":10000000,\"keyspace\":\""+keyspaceName+'\u0022' +",\"analysis\": "
                + "{\"normalizer\":{\"testnormalizer\": {\"type\": \"custom\",\"char_filter\": [],\"filter\": [\"asciifolding\"]}}}},"
                + "\"mappings\":{\""+tableName+"\":{\"discover\" : \".*\",\"properties\":{";
        indexString.append(test);

        for (String i : indexColumns)
        {
            indexString.append('\u0022'+i+'\u0022' +":" +"{ \"type\": \"keyword\",\"normalizer\": \"testnormalizer\"}" + ",");

        }
        indexString.delete(indexString.length()-1, indexString.length()).append("}}}}");

        indexQuery = indexString.toString();
        logger.info("index query is " + indexQuery);
        CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest(tableName);
        request.source(indexQuery, XContentType.JSON);
        
        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse= restHighLevelClient.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

while printing the query before calling restHighLevel client :

index query is

```
{"settings": {"max_result_window":10000000,"keyspace":"ndl","analysis": {"normalizer":{"testnormalizer": {"type": "custom","char_filter": [],"filter": ["asciifolding"]}}}},"mappings":{"initest2":{"discover" : ".*","properties":{"name":{ "type": "keyword","normalizer": "testnormalizer"}}}}}
```

Please assist if any method to be updated in java code / any properties to be updated in elassandra

Current versrion of elasticsearch : 6.8.4

Note : tried using request.settings() & request.mappings() but it didnt help

Comment: The `"initest2":{"discover" : ".*",` looks wrong to me

Comment: removed discover filed and tested , still facing the issue .. Can u please guide on what can be checked further ..  is there any method to check whether index mapping is empty or not once index is created

Comment: getting this exception if we remove discover .... but table is craeted properly with text type  Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to execute query:null : Existing column [name] type [text] mismatch with inferred type [list<text>]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=configuration_exception,